# simple string manipulation in python

Tags: python

How can I obtain the expected result below?

```
import glob
infiles = glob.glob('E:\\test\\*.txt')
print infiles
['E:\\test\\a.txt', 'E:\\test\\b.txt', 'E:\\test\\c.txt', 'E:\\test\\d.txt']
```

Expected result is:

```
'E:\\test\\a.txt','E:\\test\\b.txt','E:\\test\\c.txt','E:\\test\\d.txt'
```

My attempt is:

```
infiles = ','.join(x for x in infiles)
print infiles
E:\test\a.txt,E:\test\b.txt,E:\test\c.txt,E:\test\d.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print ','.join(map(repr, infiles))
```

You're looking for an output containing the `repr` representations of the strings in the lists, not the literal character contents of the strings. Mapping `repr` over the list gets you that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
import glob
infiles = glob.glob('E:\\test\\*.txt')
print infiles.__str__()[1:-1]
```

`print` is actually `print infiles.__str__()` under the hood, and you only want to get rid of the `[` and `]`...

Comment: Rather than directly calling the magic method, it's generally preferable to use the `str` built-in. Aside from stylistic issues, it correctly falls back to `__repr__` when `__str__` isn't present. That happens to not be an issue for lists, but remembering which types implement which magic methods is an unnecessary hassle.

Comment: Also, this results in spaces in the output that the desired output doesn't have. That might be an issue, or it might be unimportant.

Comment: @user2357112, Thank you for the very helpful suggestion of `str(infiles)`.